# Is possible HTML download Attribute can download multiple file without using javascript?

Tags: html, magento

I have a problem to download multiple file without JavaScript. May I know is possible HTML download Attribute can download multiple file without using JavaScript?

Below is my coding:

```html
<a  href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e" download><button style="background-color:#ED1C24;color:white" >Article</button></a>
```

For example, if I want to download these https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e and https://dco-assets.everestads.net/iCornerStore/source-images/MICROSOFTSTORE/current/cc1b5d10e9ab7ea9c03e62e1cc6172b6.png. I try to modify like below the code, but it doesn't work.

```html
<a  href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e,https://dco-assets.everestads.net/iCornerStore/source-images/MICROSOFTSTORE/current/cc1b5d10e9ab7ea9c03e62e1cc6172b6.png" download><button style="background-color:#ED1C24;color:white" >Article</button></a>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

*Note: Why I don't using Javascript because I am doing in Magento 1.7 version to add download multiple image function.

Comment: Why do you not want use Javascript?

Comment: Please add an explanation, or a link to the documentation, to clarify what the `download` atrribute does in Magento?

Comment: *Why I don't using Javascript because I am doing in Magento 1.7 version to add download multiple image function.* I can't understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer. What you want is not possible with an single HTML link only.
I can think of the following alternative possibilities without Javascript:

1. Multiple links
2. ZIP file

If you can't target a zip file, then only with multiple links.

### UPDATE (JS Version)

With pure JS it can look like this:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('multiple-dl');

el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const anchor = event.target;
  const links = anchor.getAttribute('data-dlinks');
  const linkList = links.split(',');
  
  linkList.forEach((link) => {
    console.log(link)
    window.open(link);  
  });  
})
```

```html
<a href="#" id="multiple-dl" class="" data-dlinks="https://www.links1.com,https://www.links1.com">multiple DLinks</a>
```

Comment: I want multiple links in the same button

Comment: Do you have idea?

Comment: In my opinion, this is only possible with Javascript.

Comment: Ok. I try to use Javascript. Because worry to crash the magento other function

Comment: @DavidHolly this is simple and if i were you i would do it with pure javascript instead of jquery. This way you have one dependency less. Which is always good. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Can you show simple method to download multiple with javascript?

Comment: @DavidHolly Yes i can show you an example. I updated my Answear with JS version. winodw.open doenst work in StackOverflow. That will throw a error here.

Comment: Ok. I try it first. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHolly Yes lets try. You can use onclick instead but it would be bad practice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice. but if that doesn't bother you, you can also write it in the shorter `onclick="window.open('link1'); window.open('link2');"`variant.

Comment: May I know your code cannot multiple download,right?

Comment: @DavidHolly It can multiple download.

Comment: I try your code, cannot work. Is any need plugin or you try to give me full code?

Comment: @DavidHolly No plugin. it s plain javascript. you got error message?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1isBwehmGlWDTN9mQoOmkyM70BGtKPB5j/view?usp=sharing
You can watch my video to show. Just can open 1 link and cannot download

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239978/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-david-holly).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to have your files zipped and link to that.

Which states the following:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="yourlink">Download</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('mysite.com/file1');
    window.open('mysite.com/file2');
    window.open('mysite.com/file3');
});
```

Having said this, I would still go with zipping the file, as this implementation requires JavaScript and can also sometimes be blocked as popups.

Option 2 is to have multiple link to the download button.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="yourlink">Click Here</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://yoururl1.com');
    window.open('http://yoururl2.com');
});
```

Minimized Code for multiple links in one button:

```
<a href="http://google.com" 
     onclick="window.open('http://web1.com','','width=700,height=700'); 
               window.open('http://web2.com','','width=700,height=500');"
               >Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Cannot download the file just can open, right?